# Having problems with making a chat in python

Tags: python

So basically I am trying to make a chat using python and I want to make a GUI for it using tkinter, I run the code and everything is normal everything except my GUI, it should be showing the name of the one who sends the message and the message itself but instead of that it's showing {self.name}:{self.msg} and here is the code:

```
def sendMessage(self):
        self.textCons.config(state=DISABLED)
        while True:
              message = "{self.name}: {self.msg}"
              client.send(message.encode(FORMAT))
              break
```

Comment: `message = f"{self.name}: {self.msg}"`

Comment: Did you mean: `message = f"{self.name}: {self.msg}"`?

Comment: Iti s pointless to have  a `while True` and `break` right after that. It is equivalent to not having the while at all.

Comment: It looks like you wanted to  use [python string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#1-old-style-string-formatting-operator). use a preceding `f`, as already commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the message you have to do:

```
message = "{0}: {1}".format(self.name, self.msg)
```

then in your while loop you do:

```
while True:
    #do something
    break
```

that iterates only one time, so if you want only one repetition you have to do:

```
#do something
```

Else if you want to do it more times you can use a `for x in range()` loop or a while loop where you stop if a condition occurs